# Accessing phone microphone with WebAudioAPI results in no sound (or distorted sound) being detected

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, microphone, pitch-detection

I am working on a guitar tuner PWA, and have implemented 2 pitch detection algorithms in order to see which is the best. The app is supposed to work by getting the audio data through a microphone connected to the device.

In order to get the audio data, I am using the following function from the WebAudioAPI in order to access the device microphone:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: {
          autoGainControl: false,
          echoCancellation: false,
          noiseSuppression: false,
        },
})
```

On desktop, everything works, and the microphone audio is picked up and both the algorithms work just as expected.

On mobile, when testing on a Oneplus 6, everything works just like on desktop. But after trying to test on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10 the algorithms don't detect anything frequency.

For my first attempt to figure out what is going on I have tried outputting the sound captured by the microphone back through speakers in order for me to check if the microphone detects any sound. On desktop and the Oneplus 6, I can hear back my voice just normal.

On the Samsung phone the audio either sounds like that static from the old tvs or like phone interference [Sound demo here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BINQNedOxM8&ab_channel=Soundsnap). My intuition tells me that this may be because the samsung phone has more microphones (either 2 or three) and that may mess up with the application since I am not specifying in any way which microphone to use. That is just a hunch though.

So, does anyone have any ideas how I may proceed towards solving this issue? Or how can explicitly control with WebAudioAPI which microphones I want to use?